# контроль записываемых данных в Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Здравствуйте!
В консольном приложении на с#, использующем Entity Framework надо произвести контроль записываемых данных.
Entity Framework делает это самостоятельно при выполнении метода SaveChanges(SaveChangesAsync). 
Но при этом диагностика самого общего вида. Типа: При обновлении записей возникла ошибка. Хотелось бы проводить более детальную диагностику (как, например, средства валидации в ASP.NET MVC). Есть ли такие средства в Entity Framework (других пакетах) или такую диагностику надо производить самостоятельно?

Заранее благодарен 
Владимир

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном случае ваш выбор = System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

Грубо говоря - это набор предопределенных атрибутов которыми можно описывать ограничения для каждого свойства в классе, описывающем модель данных. Есть набор предопределенных ограничений (напр. RequiredAttribute, MaxLengthAttribute, EmailAttribute, ReqularExpressionAttribute...). Кроме того, имеется возможность создавать собственные кастомные атрибуты, наследуясь от базового интерфейса.  Также вы можете добавть к любому аттрибуту собственное сообщение об ошибке валидации.

```
public class CreditCardStandartInfo
{
    [Required]
    [RegularExpression("^[0-9]{16}$", ErrorMessage = "incorrect format")]       
    public string CardNumber { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MinLength(6)]
    public string CardholderName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [RegularExpression("^[0-9]{3}$", ErrorMessage = "incorrect format")]
    public string CVVCode { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual int ExpireMonth { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual int ExpireYear { get; set; }
}
```

Если вы используете EF CodeFirst, то можете приделать аттрибуты прямо к модели данных. И EF во время валидации автоматически учтет их.

Если же у вас ModelFirst (нет прямого доступа к классам сущностей), то предлагаю добавить слой DTO объектов и наложить атрибуты на них. И осуществлять проверку самостоятельно. Для этого предлагаю использовать следующий код:

```
public static class DataAnnotationsValidator
{
    public static bool TryValidate(object instance, out ICollection<ValidationResult> results)
    {
        var context = new ValidationContext(instance, serviceProvider: null, items: null);
        results = new List<ValidationResult>();
        return Validator.TryValidateObject(
               instance, context, results,
               validateAllProperties: true
        );
    }
}
```

Если найдены ошибки, вам вернется их список, который вы предоставите клиенту. В случае же успеха валидации, вы копируете данные из своих DTO объектов в сущности EF и выполняете нужные операции с БД.

Comment: Спасибо за подробный и обстоятельный ответ. Буду копать в это сторону.

Comment: @ВладимирМадорин тогда стоит пометить мой ответ как верный.